# Props in state anti pattern

Tags: reactjs

So i was reading the react docs which suggest using props in state is considered to be an anti pattern. I wanted to know what the write way is. I have a parent state container passing data to a child component which also has a state.

```
constructor(props) {
  this.state = {
    name = this.props.name
  }
}
```

So i was wondering is it ok if i update the state in the CDM method

```
constructor(props) {
  this.state = {
    name = ''
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({name : this.props.name})
}
```

Any help or discussion here would be grateful.

Comment: Call props directly in render.

Comment: But incase i have a controlled input like a text field?

Comment: Raise event to parent if value changed.
Then parent has responsibility to update (or not update!) the props. The parent has full control over this text field. (hence "controlled" comes from)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using props in state is a big no no. Here is an example how to do deal with situations like these

```
class Parent extends Component {
    state = {
        name: 'John Doe'
    }

    updateName = (name) => {
        this.setState({ name });
    };

    render() {
        return (
           <div>
                <label>Your Name</label>
                <Input value={this.state.name} updateName={this.updateName} />
           </div>
        );
    }
}

class Input extends Component {
    handleUpdate = (e) => {
        this.props.updateName(e.target.value);
    };

    render() {
        return <input value={this.props.value} onChange={this.handleUpdate} />
    }   
}
```